# can't ssh into my server but VNC works

Tags: server, ssh, vnc

I can't login into my ubuntu server. When I try using SSH it's not working and if I try VNC it works normally. I can't just start anything or `sudo apt update`. It just looks like the server is offline or something like this. My firewall is also turned off. I tried restarting it multiple times but nothing is helping

EDIT:
I tried `ping google.com` and it throws `Temporary failure in name resolution`
when i try to ping an ip like 1.1.1.1 it throws `Network is unreachable`

My log when i try to `ssh <myip> -vvvv`

```
D:\>ssh 62.171.164.217 -vvvv
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\P33tT/.ssh/config
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 62.171.164.217 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 62.171.164.217 [62.171.164.217] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000002749F895000
debug1: connect to address 62.171.164.217 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 62.171.164.217 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

It looks like the server is offline because i cannot ping google.com or 1.1.1.1. When i ping the server from my pc it just says the request timed out. When i tried to boot the rescue system, internet works perfectly

Comment: @user68186 Posted the log into the edit. The ssh 127.0.0.1 via vnc worked fine

Comment: @user68186 Same stuff. It looks like the server is offline because if i try to ping like google or 1.1.1.1 via VNC it will fail

Comment: @user68186 Done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137824/discussion-between-peter-and-user68186).

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by executing

```
ip link set eth0 down

ip link set eth0 up

dhclient eth0
```

Only bad thing is that i need to do it on every server start